# swift ios http request pull data and show only data selected data value

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

I have my code below thats pull the data from an api using alamofire http request. api used https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. i can get all the data but what i want to know is that i want to get all the data but i only what to show in the collection which for example title is equal to this "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit" show only title which value is equal to what i have stated above. for example there were a lot of name values but i want only to show whos name: "Dun". Thank You.

Sample Api

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },


var getAllDetail: [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBAction func signOutButtonIsPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.showLoginScreen()
}
@IBOutlet var signoutButton: UIButton!
var items = [Item]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.signoutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    demoApi()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton =  true

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return getAllDetail.count
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
        cell.nameLabel.text = getTempDetails["title"] as? String  ?? "" //titleArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    if let getTempDetails: [String : Any] = getAllDetail[indexPath.row] {
        print("You selected ID #\( getTempDetails["userId"] as? String  ?? "" )!")
    }

}

func demoApi() {
    Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
            print("Response \(json)")
            for item in json {

                self.getAllDetail.append(item)

                // if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                //   self.titleArray.append(title)
                // }

            }
            if !self.getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            break


        case .failure(_):
            print("Error")
            break

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can possibly fetch only the title From Array and Then use like If tittle == "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to your sample response:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }
```

**You can use like this:-**

```
var dict = response as! NSDictionary

 let title = dict.value(forKey: "title")
 print(title)


 if title == "your text"{
         print("Matched")
    }else{
        print("Not Matched")

    }
```

Edit Implement in you web Response:-

**Sample Response:**

```
    { 
"id": 51, 
"name": "uuuuuuuu", 
"desc": "ahahah", 
"reward": "1.00", 
"sched": "2015-01-01T08:00:00+08:00", 
"parent": "", 
"child": "", 
"occurrence": { 
"name": "once" 
}, 
"status": "expired", 
"date_created": "2018-04-06T11:46:46.131836+08:00", 
"date_modified": "2018-04-09T13:16:44.088716+08:00" 
}
```

**Use like this:**

```
    let dictOccurence = dict["occurrence"] as! NSDictionary
    let strname = dictOccurence["name"]
    print(strname!)


    if strname == "your text"{
         print("Matched")
    }else{
        print("Not Matched")

    }
```